# Count how many "things" are being put in array from input file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

This is the beginnings of a program that will read the numbers in an input file and put them into an array, and then sort them ascending and print them into an output file.

I am having trouble with the function that records how many numbers there are in the input file (I am trying to do this while putting the numbers in the array).

Here is the code of the function. There are no errors. Whenever I run the program it prints the amount of numbers in the input as 0.

```
int store (int arg[], int numsize, istream& infile) 
{
    while (infile >> arg[  //i dont know what to put here//  ]) {
    numsize++;
    }
return numsize;   
}
```

Comment: How are there no errors, your function has a single line comment in the while-loop's conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- In order to put anything in the square brackets, you need to be sure that `arg` has enough space for it
- However, you cannot be sure of that, because you have no idea how many items will be entered
- Taking `numsize` as a parameter is useless, because you can't modify it anyway.
- This code ignores C++ Standard Library containers in favor of C-style arrays.

Fortunately, all of this can be fixed with switching your container from C-style arrays to `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> arg;
```

Now the entire read operation could then be finished in a single line of code:

```
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(infile),
    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(arg)
);
```

You do not need to count elements in your code, because `arg.size()` provides you with access to the number of elements that have been read.

Comment: your comment makes perfect sense thank you. however, my professor wants a function that that returns the number of numbers in the input file using an array (even though there are much simpler ways to build the same program) array can hold 20

Comment: @Morgan If you can pre-allocate array, and you know for sure that the file isn't going to be bigger than that, replace your loop with `while (infile >> arg[numsize++]) ;` (yes, a semicolon, with no curly braces).

Comment: the compiler printed "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and then exited.

Comment: fixed that now it just prints extremely large numbers, I will try using different types of loops.

Comment: @Morgan make array `int data[20];` then call `int count = store(data, 0, infile);` It should get you the data correctly. Print `data[i]` for `i` between 0 and `count-1`, inclusive.

Comment: I used this last night and it finally worked ' while(!infile.eof())
 {
  numsize++;
  if(numsize<20)
  {
   cout << numsize;
   infile >> arg[numsize];
  }
 }'